# HTML код пропадает со страницы после оправки формы

Tags: php, html

Реализовал простую админку на сайте. Она состоит из двух форм для создания коллекции фотографий, в первую форму вводятся все нужные строки как название, расположение, и т.п., также вводиться количество фотографий в коллекции. После ее оправки генерируются все нужные столбцы в строке коллекции в БД, в том числе нужное количество строк фотографий, которое было указано в форме, для них генерируются имена. Данный этап работает абсолютно нормально, все что нужно в БД создается и создается корректно. Далее, после обновления БД, обновляется страница на ней по isset сабмита предыдущей формы открывается форма для загрузки фото, в ней генерируется нужное количество input для фотографий в зависимости от того, сколько их было указано, после выбора файлов они загружаются на сервер по уже готовым именам из БД. На этом этапе что-то идет не так. HTML код страницы обрезается до . Скажите, в чем может быть причина? Никаких команд, которые могут обрезать код нету, ставил error_reporting(E_ALL), ничего. Что странно абсолютно аналогичным образом на этой странице можно создать статью, также с помощью двух форм, отличается только тем, что в коллекции загружается обложка и массив фото, длинна которого зависит от указоного в форме количества, а в статье только фото для preview. Статьи нормально добавляются без каких либо проблем.

Вот исходный код страницs:

```
    <?php 
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['new_col']) || isset($_POST['create_article'])){
        $_SESSION['auth'] = "completed";
    }
    if($_SESSION['auth'] == "completed"){
        echo '<font color="green">Авторизация прошла успешно</font>';
    }else {
        echo '<font color="red" size="5vh"><p align="center" style="margin-top: 20vh"><b>Отказ в доступе.</b></p></font> <br><font color="red" size="4vh"><p align="center">Вы не авторизовались.</p></font>';
        $html = preg_replace('#<div id="admin_panel">(.*?)</div>#', '', $html);
    }
    require('includes/config.php');
    $last_collection = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `collections` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1");
    $last_col = mysqli_fetch_assoc($last_collection);

    $last_article = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `articles` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1");
    $last_art = mysqli_fetch_assoc($last_article);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Admin tools | Borys Andresiuk</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/admin_tools.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/screen_16x10.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/screen_4x3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/screen_9x16.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.3.1.slim.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/admin_tools.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/create_check.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <main id="admin_panel" <?php if($_SESSION['auth'] != "completed"){echo 'style="display: none"';} if(isset($_POST['new_col']) || isset($_POST['create_article'])){$_SESSION['auth'] = "completed";}else{$_SESSION['auth'] = "";}?>>
        <div class="admin_title">Панель инструментов админа</div>
        <nav class="tools_menu">
            <div class="tools_title">Инструменты:</div>
            <li><button class="tool_btn" id="collection_btn">Создать коллекцию</button></li>
            <li><button class="tool_btn" id="article_btn">Создать статью</button></li>
            <div class="translate_block">
            <li><a href="https://translate.google.com/?hl=ru#ru/uk/" target="_blank"><button class="tool_btn translate" id="article_btn">Перевод на украинский</button></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://translate.google.com/?hl=ru" target="_blank"><button class="tool_btn translate" id="article_btn">Перевод на английский</button></a></li>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <?php 
                    if(isset($_POST['new_col'])){

                        $name = $_POST['name'];
                        $name_rus = $_POST['name_rus'];
                        $name_ukr = $_POST['name_ukr'];
                        $location = $_POST['location'];
                        $location_rus = $_POST['location_rus'];
                        $location_ukr = $_POST['location_ukr'];
                        $intro_text = $_POST['intro_text'];
                        $intro_text_rus = $_POST['intro_text_rus'];
                        $intro_text_ukr = $_POST['intro_text_ukr'];

                        $name = trim($name);
                        $name_rus = trim($name_rus);
                        $name_ukr = trim($name_ukr);
                        $location = trim($location);
                        $location_rus = trim($location_rus);
                        $location_ukr = trim($location_ukr);
                        $intro_text = trim($intro_text);
                        $intro_text_rus = trim($intro_text_rus);
                        $intro_text_ukr = trim($intro_text_ukr);

                        $id = $last_col['id'] + 1;
                        $date = date("Y-m-d");
                        $col_img = str_replace(" ", "_", mb_strtolower($name)) . ".jpg";

                        if(
                        mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO `collections` (`id`, `name`, `name_rus`, `name_ukr`, `date`, `location`, `location_rus`, `location_ukr`, `code`, `intro_text`, `intro_text_rus`, `intro_text_ukr`, `img`) VALUES ('".$id."', '".$name."', '".$name_rus."', '".$name_ukr."', '".$date."', '".$location."', '".$location_rus."', '".$location_ukr."', '".$id."', '".$intro_text."', '".$intro_text_rus."', '".$intro_text_ukr."', '".$col_img."')")
                        ){
                            $db_updated = true;
                        }else {
                            $db_updated = false;
                        }

                        $ph_quantity = trim($_POST['ph_quantity']);
                        for($i = 1; $i <= $ph_quantity; $i++){
                            $ph_img = str_replace(" ", "_", mb_strtolower($name)) . $i .".jpg";
                            mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO `photos` (`collection_id`, `img`, `code`, `location`, `location_rus`, `location_ukr`, `big`) VALUES ('".$id."', '".$ph_img."', '".$i."', '".$location."', '".$location_rus."', '".$location_ukr."', '0')");

                        }

                        $countries_filters = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `countries`");
                        if(strpos($location, ",") !== false){
                            $cur_contry = mb_substr($location, 0, strpos($location, ","));
                        }else {
                            $cur_contry = $location;
                        }
                        $c_exists = false;
                        while($country = mysqli_fetch_assoc($countries_filters)){
                            if($cur_contry == $country['name']){
                                $c_exists = true;
                                exit;
                            }
                        }
                        if(!$c_exists){
                            if(strpos($location_rus, ",") !== false){
                                $cur_contry_rus = mb_substr($location_rus, 0, strpos($location_rus, ","));
                            }else {
                                $cur_contry_rus = $location_rus;
                            }
                            if(strpos($location_ukr, ",") !== false){
                                $cur_contry_ukr = mb_substr($location_ukr, 0, strpos($location_ukr, ","));
                            }else {
                                $cur_contry_ukr = $location_ukr;
                            }
                            if(
                                mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO `countries` (`name`, `name_rus`, `name_ukr`) VALUES ('".$cur_contry."', '".$cur_contry_rus."', '".$cur_contry_ukr."')")
                            ){
                                $db_updated = true;
                            }else {
                                $db_updated = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if(isset($_POST['create_article'])){

                        $title = $_POST['title'];
                        $title_rus = $_POST['title_rus'];
                        $title_ukr = $_POST['title_ukr'];
                        $text = $_POST['text'];
                        $text_rus = $_POST['text_rus'];
                        $text_ukr = $_POST['text_ukr'];

                        $title = trim($title);
                        $title_rus = trim($title_rus);
                        $title_ukr = trim($title_ukr);
                        $text = trim($text);
                        $text_rus = trim($text_rus);
                        $text_ukr = trim($text_ukr);

                        $art_id = $last_art['id'] + 1;
                        $art_date = date("Y-m-d");
                        $art_img = "ev" . $art_id . ".jpg";
                        if(
                            mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO `articles` (`id`, `img`, `text`, `text_rus`, `text_ukr`, `title`, `title_rus`, `title_ukr`, `date`) VALUES ('".$art_id."', '".$art_img."', '".$text."', '".$text_rus."', '".$text_ukr."', '".$title."', '".$title_rus."', '".$title_ukr."', '".$art_date."')")
                        ){
                            $art_updated = true;
                        }else {
                            $art_updated = false;
                        }
                    }
                ?>

        <div class="create_form" id="create_collection_form">
            <form action="admin_tools_page.php" method="POST">

                <div class="form_title">Создать коллекцию</div>

                <label for="name_rus" class="form_label">Введите название коллекции на <b>русском</b></label>
                <input type="text" name="name_rus" id="name_rus" class="form_input">
                <label for="name" class="form_label">Введите название коллекции на <b>английском</b></label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form_input">
                <label for="name_ukr" class="form_label">Введите название коллекции на <b>украинском</b></label>
                <input type="text" name="name_ukr" id="name_ukr" class="form_input"> 

                <label for="location_rus" class="form_label">Введите место создания коллекции на <b>русском</b></label>
                <input type="text" name="location_rus" id="location_rus" class="form_input">
                <label for="location" class="form_label">Введите место создания коллекции на <b>английском</b></label>
                <input type="text" name="location" id="location" class="form_input">
                <label for="location_ukr" class="form_label">Введите место создания коллекции на <b>украинском</b></label>
                <input type="text" name="location_ukr" id="location_ukr" class="form_input">

                <label for="intro_text_rus" class="form_label">Введите ознакомительный текст коллекции на <b>русском</b></label>
                <textarea name="intro_text_rus" id="intro_text_rus" class="form_textarea"></textarea>
                <label for="intro_text" class="form_label">Введите ознакомительный текст коллекции на <b>английском</b></label>
                <textarea name="intro_text" id="intro_text" class="form_textarea"></textarea>
                <label for="intro_text_ukr" class="form_label">Введите ознакомительный текст коллекции на <b>украинском</b></label>
                <textarea name="intro_text_ukr" id="intro_text_ukr" class="form_textarea"></textarea>

                <label for="ph_quantity" class="form_label">Введите количество фотографий в коллекции</label>
                <input type="text" name="ph_quantity" id="ph_quantity" class="form_input">

                <input type="submit" name="new_col" id="create_collection" value="Создать" class="create_btn">
            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="create_form" id="img_col_form" <?php if(isset($_POST['new_col'])){echo 'style="display: block"';}?>>
            <?php if($db_updated){echo '<font color="green">Коллекция успешно создана, вы можете добавлять фотографии</font>';}else{echo '<font color="red" size="4vh">Возникли проблемы при подключении к базе данных.</font>';}?>

            <form method="POST" action="includes/upload_img.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo ini_get("session.upload_progress.name"); ?>" value="images">
                <div class="form_title">Добавение фотографий</div>

                <label for="col_wrap" class="form_label">Укажите фотографию для обложки коллекции</label>

                <label for="col_wrap">
                    <input type="file" name="col_wrap" id="col_wrap" class="file">
                </label>
                <label for="col_photos[]" class="form_label">Добавляйте по одному фото в коллекцию</label>

                <?php 
                    for($i = 0; $i < $_POST['ph_quantity']; $i++){
                ?>
                <label>
                    <input type="file" name="col_photos[]" class="file">
                    <span class="ph_big">
                        <label for="big">Большая</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="big<?php echo $i + 1?>">
                    </span>
                </label>
                <?php 
                    }
                ?>

                <input type="submit" name="col_img_post" value="Отправтиь" class="create_btn">
            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="create_form" id="create_article_form">
            <form action="admin_tools_page.php" method="POST">

                <div class="form_title">Создать статью</div>

                <label for="title_rus" class="form_label">Введите название статьи на <b>русском</b></label>
                <input type="text" name="title_rus" id="title_rus" class="form_input">
                <label for="title" class="form_label">Введите название статьи на <b>английском</b></label>
                <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form_input">
                <label for="title_ukr" class="form_label">Введите название статьи на <b>украинском</b></label>
                <input type="text" name="title_ukr" id="title_ukr" class="form_input"> 

                <label for="text_rus" class="form_label">Введите текст статьи на <b>русском</b></label>
                <textarea name="text_rus" id="text_rus" class="form_textarea"></textarea>
                <label for="text" class="form_label">Введите текст статьи на <b>английском</b></label>
                <textarea name="text" id="text" class="form_textarea"></textarea>
                <label for="text_ukr" class="form_label">Введите текст статьи на <b>украинском</b></label>
                <textarea name="text_ukr" id="text_ukr" class="form_textarea"></textarea>

                <input type="submit" name="create_article" id="create_article" value="Создать" class="create_btn">
            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="create_form" id="img_art_form" <?php if(isset($_POST['create_article'])){echo 'style="display: block"';}?>>

            <?php if($art_updated){echo '<font color="green">Статья успешно создана, вы можете добавить фотографию</font>';}else{echo '<font color="red" size="4vh">Возникли проблемы при подключении к базе данных.</font>';}?>

            <form method="POST" action="includes/upload_img.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo ini_get("session.upload_progress.name"); ?>" value="images">
                <div class="form_title">Добавение фотографий</div>          

                <label for="art_img" class="form_label">Укажите фотографию для обложки статьи</label>

                <label for="art_img">
                    <input type="file" name="art_img" id="art_img" class="file">
                </label>

                <input type="submit" name="art_img_post" value="Отправтиь" class="create_btn">
            </form>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
<?php 
    require('includes/close_db.php');
?>
</html>
```

Вот как он обрезается:

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <title>Admin tools | Borys Andresiuk</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/admin_tools.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/screen_16x10.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/screen_4x3.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/screen_9x16.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.3.1.slim.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/admin_tools.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/create_check.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <main id="admin_panel" >
            <div class="admin_title">Панель инструментов админа</div>
            <nav class="tools_menu">
                <div class="tools_title">Инструменты:</div>
                <li><button class="tool_btn" id="collection_btn">Создать коллекцию</button></li>
                <li><button class="tool_btn" id="article_btn">Создать статью</button></li>
                <div class="translate_block">
                <li><a href="https://translate.google.com/?hl=ru#ru/uk/" target="_blank"><button class="tool_btn translate" id="article_btn">Перевод на украинский</button></a></li>
                <li><a href="https://translate.google.com/?hl=ru" target="_blank"><button class="tool_btn translate" id="article_btn">Перевод на английский</button></a></li>
                </div>
            </nav>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: http://phpfaq.ru/debug

Comment: не пытались код покомпактнее писать, без копипаста?
`$fields = ['name', 'name_rus', ..] ; foreach($fields as $f){ $values[$f] = trim($_POST[$field]); }`. +там еще про подгтовленные выражения для вставки в БД и т.д.

Comment: `</body></html>` это вам браузер в инспекторе небось дописывает. в исходном тексте страницы их вероятно нет. Возможно потому что в одном из циклов у вас почему то `exit` вместо `break`

Comment: Да,Вы правы, в исходном коде их нету, попробую исправить exit.

Comment: @teran Вы абсолютно правы, с break все работает, после exit выполнение скрипта прекращалось.